# How to override a device tree and move a node?

Tags: linux, kernel, device-tree

I have a dts file that includes a rather generic dtsi file but needs to remove a node from one subtree and move it to another.  If I simply go in the base dts and add the node to where it should be, the resulting dtb has both the original as well as the new.

original dtsi:

```
a {
    b1 {
    };
    b2 {
       c {};
    };   
};
```

override:

```
#include "original.dtsi"

a {
    b1{
        c{};
    };
};
```

The problem is that I then have a 'c' node in both 'b1' and 'b2'

Comment: Your Device Tree should describe the actual hardware that the kernel is going to execute on.  Is the hardware represented by node `c` connected to `b1` or `b2`?  Maybe you will have to start from scratch, and not use that "original" dtsi file?

Comment: In this case c is attached to b1, but the dts base has c connected to b2. I'd like to base this new dts on the previous, since other than this small change, the hardware is identical, and I'd rather not have to mirror changes everywhere.

Comment: "*but the dts base has c connected to b2"* -- Then you should try to redefine/overlay `b2` (wthout `c`) in your **dtsi**.

Comment: Yeah that's what we ended up doing. Was hoping there was an easier way, since b2 has a lot of other stuff that we now need to maintain in two places.

Comment: *"we now need to maintain in two places"* -- Why two places?  Only the `b2` node in your **dtsi** should matter, since it would be the overlay node.

Comment: Yes we need to maintain b2 in two different places. Once contains C and a bunch of stuff, the other contains the extra stuff. It's right on the cusp of 'worthy of its own dtsi'